# Class property 'current' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Thread.current cannot be used from async contexts.; this is an error in Swift 6

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to figure out what thread or run loop I am on when in an async task. How can I get the thread or run loop from a task?

```swift
Task {
    do {
        print("line: ", #line, Thread.current)
        let image = try await self.fetchImage()
        print("line: ", #line, Thread.current)
    } catch {
        let fetch: FetchError = error as! FetchError
        print("line: ", #line, Thread.current)
    }
    print("line: ", #line, Thread.current)
}
print("line: ", #line)
```

When I try my typical method (i.e. `Thread.current`), I get:

```plaintext
Class property 'current' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; Thread.current cannot be used from async contexts.; this is an error in Swift 6.
```

It still runs but the warning makes me believe I can't trust the result.

Comment: Have a look at Instruments. In Xcode 14 the visualisation of the threads is much more convenient than `print` lines.

Answer (score 8):

Your result is probably okay, but the warning is right too: what you're doing is illegal, and will be made formally illegal in a future version of Swift. So start now by not doing it.

In general, do not speak of threads *at all* in the context of `async/await`. They are of no interest to you. You can ask for `Thread.isMainThread` but that's really it (unless it too now has a warning; I haven't checked). Just let `async/await` do its thing and be happy.

If you're using these `print` lines just to get a sense for what async/await is doing with threads, a good alternative would be to use `NSLog` and output the line number only. `NSLog` automatically tells you thread number as part of its output, so no need to call any Thread methods at all.

Comment: You did not explain in your question why you _think_ knowing more than whether this is the main thread is important to you, so your question might be an XY question. What I've answered, though, is the question you _did_ ask.

Comment: I am generally trying to learn about async await and how the program execution flows and why.

Comment: Cool, so for now you can just keep using your code and accept the warnings. You'll delete the `print` statements in shipping code anyway. But in my experience asking whether this is the main thread is _all_ you need to know in order to check what async/await is doing.

Comment: Alternatively you could use NSLog; it tells you what thread this is, automatically, for free, no matter _what_ you choose to print. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Good to know that `NSLog` automatically prints information about the thread  However, `NSLog` calls don't show up in the console in Swift Playgrounds so I have to stick to `print` in that context.

Comment: FWIW, `Thread.isMainThread` does throw the same warning in the async context.

Comment: FWIW I personally don't think it's helpful to encourage people not to think of threads. In Apple's own content they repeatedly refer to threads. The first line of their "adopting swift concurrency guide" starts with "In a SwiftUI app, the main thread executes all UI work". Then it mentions threads three times in the three sentences of the opening paragraph. Similarly for the WWDC sessions on async/await and actors. It's helpful to understand one layer under the abstraction, and I think that applies to async/await just as well as any other concept.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this: https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-unavailability-from-asynchronous-contexts/53877

It explains that a swift Task can be run on different threads before or after a suspension point. Therefore, accessing “local thread information” inside a Task closure can be dangerous (if you read thread information before the suspension point, and use that information after the suspension point, in another thread).

So, as your code is just reading Tread.current() before and after, the fetchImage() suspension point, it is probably safe - but you can get different results from the two calls.

Now, would your code read Tread.current() before the suspension point,  and use it after, it would be unsafe.

For this reason, the Tread.current() declaration is marked as available(*, noasync), which today raises a warning, and tomorrow (Swift 6) will be an error.

Note that the link mentions how this can be worked around when you face a valid use case.